# Can you set up redirects via an FTP client

Tags: ftp, web-hosting

A client asked me to set up a redirect from her site to another site and gave me the FTP login username and password.  From what I understand, FTP access only lets you upload and download files.  I believe you need to access the host itself to set up a redirect.

Is this true, or can I set the redirect up with FTP access only?

Comment: did the client give the IP address of server for which FTP u/p has been given ?

Comment: yes.  Sorry for the delayed response

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just got access to the host account itself, which I recommend any web developer do to set up redirects.

Answer (score 1):

If this FTP login lets you access the document root of some apache server, you could use .htaccess files to implement the redirect.

In a .htaccess file you use commands like `RewriteRule` to implement the redirect you are looking for, as soon a request is accessing the directory with the .htaccess file in it, apache reads it and executes it.

This is a description of howto do redirects in apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

And this is about .htaccess files:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html